# How to loop URL and stream data in php

Tags: php, curl, server-sent-events

Hi I'm trying server sent events using `php`, I have a https url where I get the stream data in every action. I need to run some scripts where I need to get a flow of data 24/7.

The script should run in background all the time.

```
<?php 
   $ch = curl_init('https://api.abc.com:8100/update-stream/connect');    
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); 
   $response = curl_exec($ch);       
   print_r($response);
?>
```

How can I make this `curl` as a Server Sent Event, which always runs and checks for an updates?

Comment: have you tried cron job

Comment: Cron job, can we use for Server Sent Events. because its a stream data comes from other server, we dont no when the data will be coming to our server. our script should be ready to get data.

Comment: Server side `while(1) {/**/}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This something can help you.

```
<?php
   header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
   header("Connection: keep-alive");

   while (true)
   {  
        //your logic can go here
   }  

?>
```

Comment: hey! Khalid if we make it while true an infinite loop, it will be keep on executing which loads to server right?